# ob_get_contents() - get data from open body tag to close body tag

Tags: php

Quick question, is there a way to specify exactly what contents to pull from ob_get_contents() in php.

I have the following code.. but still no luck..

```
$no = mt_rand(100,10000);    
$page = ob_get_contents();  
$custompage = preg_match('/<body[^>]+./','', $page);
ob_end_clean();

$filename1 = $no.'doc.html';

$f = fopen('./view/'.$filename1, "w"); 
fwrite($f, $custompage); 
fclose($f);
```

What I want is to select just the html generated from php script (between the body tag) and save it to a file. Saving the file works.

Any help, will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: So... you need the HTML between `<body>` and `</body>`?

Comment: @JánosWeisz yes..that exactly what I need. At the moment, I get the full page... from html tag to closing html tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex might be an overkill for this task. It is logical to assume you have exactly one `<body>`, and one `</body>` substring in your outputted page.

All we have to do in this case is determining the string position of these two, and fire up a `substr`:

```
$from = strpos($page, '<body>');
$to = strpos($page, '</body>');

$contents = substr($page, $from, $to - $from);
```

This will, however, include the `<body>` and `</body>` tags.

Comment: What if body is
`<body id="tesT" onload="hello();">` or so forth. Actually, the overhead isn't that bad especially if used for caching

Comment: @DimitriAdamou Good catch. I know no one-liner for that. The reason I was attempting to avoid Regex was due to the lack of its tag in the question.

Comment: Just drop the trailing `>` from the initial `from` and @DimitriAdamou's case should be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Simple one,

```
$match = "";
preg_match("/<body.+<\/body>/is", $page, $custompage);

print_r($custompage);
```

Comment: this gives me an array

Comment: Yeah, and you just do $custompage[0], that is the behavior of preg_match. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
You can not do `$string = preg_match(...);` because preg_match returns either a 1 if there is a match or a 0 if no matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through the DOM API:

Just load your page code this way:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
```

Then fetch the body "node" (as there is only one body element, we can use `item(0)`) :

```
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
```

Then you can output the body in a canonicalized form :

```
echo $body->C14N();
```

or just output the body XML code this way :

```
echo $dom->saveXML($body);
```

Just use `file_put_contents` to save it wherever you want so your code can be just :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
file_put_contents(
    "myfile.html",
    $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->C14N()
);
```

This will keep the `body` element because a DOM document must have a root, but you can get rid of it by storing every child node :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$content = "";
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $content .= $dom->saveXML($child);
}
file_put_contents("myfile.html", $content);
```

There is a bit more code than in other solutions but, according to me, it's much more clean to do it this way.